# When processing a webhook, I get an unauthorized 401

Tags: java, spring-security, push-notification, vaadin, webhooks

When processing a webhook, I get an unauthorized 401
I use Spring Security and Vaadin

```
@RestController
@Log4j2
public class WebHookController {

  @Inject
  KeywordPlanService service;
  @Inject
  SheetsService sheetsService;

  MainView view;

  @PostMapping("/notifications")
  @AnonymousAllowed
  public ResponseEntity<Void> webHookHandler(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerGoogChanged = request.getHeader("x-goog-changed");
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(headerGoogChanged) && headerGoogChanged.contains("content")) {
      service.parseDashboardAndSave(view.getGrid(), sheetsService.readSheetValuesBatch());
      sheetsService.writeSheetValuesBatch(service.getKeyWordDashboards());
      log.info("Push notification processed: {}", request);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
}
```

and

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
        .permitAll();
  }...
```

I understand that I need to make my endpoint public

> /notifications

How can I make the endpoint public?

**Updated**

```
   @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/notifications")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
    
    
      }
```

causes a message

> 2022-06-10 17:39:30.040  WARN 37089 --- [  restartedMain]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
> 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after
> anyRequest 2022-06-10 17:39:30.041  WARN 37089 --- [  restartedMain]
> .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Destroy method on bean with
> name 'keywordPlanService' threw an exception:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 2022-06-10 17:39:30.044  INFO 37089 ---
> [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping
> service [Tomcat] 2022-06-10 17:39:30.061  INFO 37089 --- [
> restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2022-06-10 17:39:30.074
> ERROR 37089 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
> 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after
> anyRequest    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
> ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]    at
> com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
> ~[main/:na]   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method
> 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after
> anyRequest    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   ... 26 common frames
> omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure
> antMatchers after anyRequest  at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.antMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:122)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> com.example.demo.config.WebSecurityConfig.configure(WebSecurityConfig.java:20)
> ~[main/:na]   at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> com.example.demo.config.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91e4ba14.init()
> ~[main/:na]   at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
> ~[spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]   ... 27 common frames
> omitted
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64031',
> transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code:

```
 .antMatchers("/notifications").permitAll()
```

So in your case it will go like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/notifications")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
```

Comment: I have updated the code
`    super.configure(http);
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/notifications").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
        .permitAll();
` 
But I get a message:
"Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest"

Comment: I'm still getting the message 
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.oauth2Login()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/notifications").permitAll();


  }
 Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Comment: Please try with code I just posted. Shoud work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not agree with deactivating security for any endpoint, even notification  should be done by authorized application.

For disabling security for a specific endpoint, try this :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/notifications").permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```